# My IE browser version is 11.239.* but when i check with code it shows version as IE version 7

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, user-agent

Consider below code:

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

In my case "request.getHeader("User-Agent")" method call returns below string.

**Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)**

but when I check my user agent string at http://useragentstring.com

it shows as **Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko**

which is correct as per browser version shown by the **IE browser**.

So My concern is that method that I am using is correct or missing something, because the same code returns proper UserAgent String in chrome and Mozilla.

Comment: erm, don't use IE anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your website, whether it set the X-UA-Compatible meta tag. Try to modify it as below:

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

As far as I know, the UserAgent string can be changed by the browser owner, such as change UserAgent string or the iexplore Emulation via the registry. Please navigate to the following registry and check whether it changes the user agent.

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\User Agent

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
```

More detail information, please check these link:

[Customize user agent string](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::Customized_UserAgent_String)

[#Browser Emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#browser_emulation)

Besides, you could also try to reset the IE browser setting, and change it to the default status.

Open IE browser -> click **Tools** and select the **Internet Options** -> select the **Advanced** tab and click the **Reset** button, checked the **Delete personal settings** checkbox and check **Reset** button.